# Why if f(x) = 2x - x on [-1, 1] results in [-1, 2] in Interval Arithmetic?

Tags: interval-arithmetic

From the Section 3.1 of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2202.02444.pdf)

> **The Dependency Problem.** The main downside of interval arithmetic is that the computed bounds may be extremely pessimistic.
> As an example, consider the simple operation  ← 2 −, evaluated
> on the range  ∈ [−1, 1]. Clearly the actual bound on  is [−1, 1],
> but applying the rules above yields a looser bound of [−1, 2] even
> in this simple example.

When I try to apply Interval Arithmetic rules I get:

$$f([-1, 1]) = [min(-2, 2), max(-2, 2)] + -1 [-1, 1] = [-2, 2] + [-1, 1] = [-3, 3]$$

I do see that this yields a looser bound but I don't understand why it becomes $[-1, 2]$

Comment: I suspect this is just a typo, but since I'm not an expert I'm going to hold off on posting that as an answer.

Comment: I have emailed the author and he confirmed it was a typo. I will be closing this question

Comment: I have emailed the author and he has confirmed it is a typo. Therefore, this question has no point.

Comment: Yes , I had come to the typo conclusion , which it is immaterial in Present Case , because the Author is skipping it , to move on to more accurate Method. The Correction & the typo have no value except to state that the Method is inaccurate.